# Permission Denied when launching Matlab

Tags: permissions, matlab

I am new to Ubuntu. When trying to open Matlab I get a Permission Denied response. How can I fix this?

```
1cqxdz1:~> /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin: Permission denied.
```

Comment: Whats the output of `ls -l /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin`?

Comment: total 512
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 22168 Aug 16  2013 activate_matlab.sh
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 22217 Aug 16  2013 deactivate_matlab.sh
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 18654 Apr 16  2010 deploytool
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root  6955 Jul  1  2013 engopts.sh
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 45056 Jan 29  2014 glnxa64
-r--r--r-- 1 root root    19 Apr 16  2010 insttype.ini
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 22586 Jun 23  2013 lcdata_utf8.xml
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 22831 Jun 23  2013 lcdata.xml
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root  3601 Apr 16  2010 lcdata.xsd
- .......etc (too long to fit in a comment back)

Comment: Is there a specific one of those files that I need to change the permissions for? (all the -r--r--r etc are the read/write/execute permissions, right?)

Comment: Whats the output of `namei -l /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin`?

Comment: f: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root usr
drwxr-xr-x root root local
drwxr-xr-x root root MATLAB
drwxr-xr-x root root R2013b
drwxr-xr-x root root bin

Comment: You should run it in the terminal as `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/matlab&`

Answer (score -1):

Turned out I need to instead type in:

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/matlab &
```

Thanks @Harris

Answer (score -2):

I think you should do:

```
sudo matlab
```

Instead of:

```
matlab
```

Comment: No, you actually shouldn't do that.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry for the wrong information.